# Connect to many SignalR hubs on different hosts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, signalr

I want to know how it is possible to create and store multiple SignalR connections on a web application (Angular in this case), to connect to multiple SignalR hosts (on different URL):

For example, if I have an instance running of my server application (hub) on 3 different computers, my web application will ask the user to introduce the host IP address and the angular application will try to connect to each device. Once each connection is established, it must receive the messages sent by the different computers throught its hub.

I have successfully implemented the connection to 1 host, but my application must be connected to n SignalR hosts.

Thank you.

Comment: Those hosts are the same hub implementation or it have different objectives? Also did you considered to use ```Azure SignalR```?

Comment: It could be the same and sometimes different. With the same web application, I need to receive data from different devices. If it is possible only with the same hub implementation, it could be possible. It can’t use Azure SignalR because the web application and the signalR hosts would be hosted on a wifi local network without internet connection

Comment: @Kiril1512 do you know any possible solution? Thanks

Comment: I don't know about wifi local network without internet connection, maybe you can ask this on the github.